# Spring Boot app is not able to read environment properties

Tags: linux, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, environment-variables

I have an Spring Boot application in which I am using environment properties for the `yml` file.

My `application.yml` looks like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${DB_URL}
    driver-class-name: ${DB_DRIVER}
    username: ${DB_USERNAME}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
    max-wait: ${database.max-wait:5000}
    max-active: ${database.max-active:500}
    test-on-borrow: ${database.test-on-borrow:true}
    initialization-mode: always
```

When I tried to deploy it in an external host  trough Tomcat the application is not able to start because it cannot read the environment variables.
I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '${DB_USERNAME}'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:227)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:350)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:343)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.java:52)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:430)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
            ... 134 more
```

I am using an Ubuntu server. I set the environment variables on `/etc/environment` and they look like this

```
DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://XX.XX.XX.XX:3306/XXXXX"
DB_USER="XXXXX"
DB_PASSWORD="XXXXX"
DB_DRIVER="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
```

When I run the command `set` they are perfectly shown there.
I also tried to create a `setenv.sh` file under `/opt/tomcat/bin` which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DB_DRIVER=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
export DB_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
export DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://XX.XX.XX.XX:3306/XXXXX
export DB_USER=XXXXXX
```

I haven't tried to do it in profile because according to this thread it should be enough with `/etc/environment`:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables

Any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: Did you make sure your `setenv.sh` is accessible by tomcat? Also that `CATALINA_BASE` and `CATALINA_HOME` are set?
Reference : [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt)

Comment: @Sajjad I have added `CATALINA_HOME` in `/etc/environments` and `setenv.sh` has read and execution permissions. Is there anything else to do?

Answer (score 0):

Could be you are entering wrong credentials. Just cross check the same credentials with some MySql GUI tools like workbench, sqlyog....

Comment: Yes I did and as you can see in the exception it's using the plain text of the environment variables in the yml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spring.config.location` to set up the explicit path for your externalized config files. Then you can configure your Spring Boot application to load them as system properties on startup.

For example

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("spring.config.location",<your config file path>);
```

Source: [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

Comment: But my problem is not where the config file is place and I would prefer to avoid externalising it. I want to be able to have spring boot reading the environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

In your spring boot properties file you are using

> ${DB_USERNAME}

and in bash config file you are using

> export DB_USER=XXXXXX

change bash file to

> export  ${DB_USERNAME}=XXXXXX